# Pixelate images when hovering over parent div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hover, jquery-isotope

Searching around for ways to do this, I found a couple good explanations out there, and ended up combining them. I had everything working fine when I was just doing the hover effect when mousing over the image itself, but when trying to make it work when hovering over the "profile" div seems to have caused some problems. Currently, it will sometimes also be pixelated when not over the div, so it remains somewhere between the mouseover and mouseout states.

### HTML

In the HTML, I'm creating a filterable directory of people using isotope that contains a bunch of blocks like this:

```
<div class="item profile p-1 undergrad research">
    <div class="profile-image">
        <img src="img.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="profile-text">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <h2>Position</h2>
        <p>
            Email:email@gmail.com<br>
            Phone: 123.345.6567<br>
            Office: 2818
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

I'm using javascript to handle the pixelation stuff right now, but to be honest I'm a lot more familiar and comfortable with Jquery, so this has been a struggle and learning experience. Below is the whole code, but I'll explain what I changed that started my issues.

Originally, "items" in setup was taking *.profile-image* objects, and I changed that to *.profile* objects so I could use the ".profile" div as the object with the mouseover event listener. At this point I introduced *"block"*, which i switched the event listeners to from *"element"*.

```
// Most of the structure taken from Noel Delgado
// @pixelia_me => http://codepen.io/noeldelgado/pen/FmEBh
// The actual pixelation taken from Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen
// http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/QznT7/

// http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

/*
**  =======================================================================
**                          Animation
**  =======================================================================
*/

var lastTime = 0;
var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame =
      window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
      || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
}

if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function(){callback(currTime + 
                 timeToCall);},
          timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };

/*
**  =======================================================================
**                          Pixelation
**  =======================================================================
*/

/*============================="Setup"===============================*/

var PIXELATION  = 36,//The value when hovering. Lower numbers are more 
                       pixelated, while 100 is not at all
    speed       = 4,//How quickly it animates.
    play        = false;//Is the animation "playing"?

var items = document.querySelectorAll('.profile'),//The parent of everything.
    _objs = [];//Array that will be filled with our images

/*===================Images Object "Class Constructor"=====================*/
var Images = function( block, element, image, canvas, context ) {
    this.block      = block;
    this.element    = element;
    this.image      = image;
    this.canvas     = canvas;
    this.context    = context;
    this.pixelation = 100;
}

//Called by Array.prototype.slice
Images.prototype.bindLoad = function() {
    var obj = this;

    this.image.onload = function() {
        obj.reportLoad.call(obj);
    };

    if ( this.image.complete ) {
        this.image.onload();
    }
}

//Called by Images.prototype.bindLoad
Images.prototype.reportLoad = function() {
    var obj = this;
        size = (play ? v : 100) * 0.01,
        w = this.width * size;
        h = this.height * size;

    this.imageWidth    = this.canvas.width   = this.image.width;
    this.imageHeight   = this.canvas.height  = this.image.height;
    this.context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, w, h);
    this.context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, 
                           this.element.width, this.element.height);

    //Turn off image smoothing so we get the pixelated effect
    this.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    this.block.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        obj.mouseOver();
    }, false);

    this.block.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        obj.mouseOut();
    }, false);
}

/*=====================Images Object MouseOver Function======================*/
Images.prototype.mouseOver = function() {
    var obj = this,
        play = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame( obj.idUndraw );
    var draw = function() {
        if ( obj.pixelation <= PIXELATION ) {
            play = false;
            cancelAnimationFrame( obj.idDraw );
            obj.pixelation = PIXELATION;
        } else {
            obj.pixelate( obj.imageWidth, obj.imageHeight, 0, 0 );
            obj.idDraw = requestAnimationFrame( draw, obj.context );
        }
    };
    obj.idDraw = requestAnimationFrame( draw, obj.context );
}

/*====================Images Object MouseOut Function==================*/
Images.prototype.mouseOut = function() {
    var obj = this,
        play = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame( obj.idDraw );
    var undraw = function() {
        if ( obj.pixelation > 98 ) {  //New Code
            play = false;//New Code
            cancelAnimationFrame( obj.idUndraw );
            obj.pixelation = 98;
        } else {
            obj.depixelate( obj.imageWidth, obj.imageHeight, 0, 0 );
            obj.idUndraw = requestAnimationFrame( undraw, obj.context );
        }
    };
    obj.idUndraw = requestAnimationFrame( undraw, obj.context );
}

/*=================Images Object Pixelation Calculation===================*/
//Called by Images.prototype.pixelate & depixelate
Images.prototype.setPixels = function() {
    size = this.pixelation * 0.01;
    w = this.image.width * size;
    h = this.image.height * size;
    this.context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, w, h);
    this.context.drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, 
                           this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
}
/*====================Images Object Pixelation Methods=====================*/
//Called by Images.prototype.mouseOver
Images.prototype.pixelate = function() {
    this.pixelation -= speed;
    this.setPixels();
}

//Called by Images.prototype.mouseOut (Line 113)
Images.prototype.depixelate = function() {
    this.pixelation += speed;
    this.setPixels();
}

/*=============================Create Array of images=====================*/
//It all seems to start here. Don't really know how this gets called 
//though unfortunately...
Array.prototype.slice.call(items, 0).forEach(function(el, i) {
    var block   = el,
        element = el.querySelector('.profile-image'),
        image   = element.querySelector('img'),
        canvas  = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    element.appendChild( canvas );

    _objs.push( new Images( block, element, image, canvas, context ) );
    _objs[i].bindLoad();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That script is pretty wrapped up in presuming it's dealing directly with images. You might try faking it by leaving it in it's original state and then using some jquery to trigger it.

```
$('.profile').on('hover', function(){

   $(this).find('img').trigger('mouseenter');

}),  function(){

   $(this).find('img').trigger('mouseleave');

});
```

Untested, obviously. :) And without seeing the original script, I'm not sure which events it was actually listening for. You may need to swap out `mouseenter` with `mouseover` or something else from http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: I was leaning towards doing something like this, but just wasn't sure how to go about it, I'll try it out and see how it goes.